# Probability of getting $n$ heads after $cn$ tosses?

Tags: probability

If $X_n$ is the number of coin tosses to get $n$ heads, then how can one show that there exists a constant $c>1$ such that $P(X_n \geq cn) \leq 1/n$?  I am looking for a direct elementary proof.

Assume the coin tosses are fair and independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X_n$ is the sum of $n$ i.i.d. geometric random variables with parameter $\frac12$, $E[X_n]=2n$ and $\mathrm{var}(X_n)=2n$. Bienaymé-Chebychev inequality implies that, for every nonnegative $x$,
$$
P[X_n\geqslant E[X_n]+x]\leqslant\mathrm{var}(X_n)/x^2.
$$
If $x^2=2n^2$, the RHS is $1/n$ and $E[X_n]+x=(2+\sqrt2)n$ hence $c=2+\sqrt2$ answers the question. Or,
$$
P[X_n\gt 4n]\leqslant1/(2n).
$$

Comment: Thank you. This would be a great answer but I was hoping, perhaps in vain, that there might be a proof that was elementary and entirely self contained.

Comment: I suppose I could just incorporate a direct proof of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality#Proof_.28of_the_two-sided_version.29 .